# Set width and height to React-native modal

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

I can't configure modal height and width using **`style`** property. Is there any other way to set modal height and width?

```
 <Modal style={{height: 300, width: 300}}
        visible={this.state.isVisible}
        onRequestClose={this.closeModal}>
 </Modal>
```

The code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

According to the [Modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#props) documentation, there is no `style` prop to be set.

You can try setting the `<View>` dimensions inside the `<Modal>` instead:

```
<Modal transparent={true}
       visible={this.state.isVisible}
       onRequestClose={this.closeModal}>
  <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{
            width: 300,
            height: 300}}>
      ...
    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

Comment: If you want the modal to appear as a distinct box with the underlying view "dimmed", to the outer view add a background color with transparency -- e.g., `backgroundColor: '#00000080'` (white with 50% opacity) and a solid color and padding to the inner view, e.g., `backgroundColor: '#fff', padding: 20`

Comment: Regarding backgroundColor of the parent, 'rgba(80,80,80,0.1)' works better for me...

Comment: don't forget to re-check if "transparent" prop is set to true

Comment: if you want to play with the Modal size depending on the device: `style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.5, height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.5}}`

Comment: For me, adding margin: 0 in the modal's style fixed the issue...

Answer (score 12):

Try adding `margin:0` in the style of the `<Modal>` Component

Answer (score 5):

In the [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal#supportedorientations) documentation it is not mentioned it but it has a style property.

The following works for me.

```
<Modal
    style={styles.modalContent}
    isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
    onBackdropPress={this.closeModal}
>
    <Component {...componentProps} />
</Modal>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modalContent: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        margin: 0
    },
});
```

Comment: yes it does have styles property but still doesnot align it in the center of the screen

Comment: There is no style prop at all. Please see the documentation again.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me after i have tried other methods, I had to give the modal some style.

```
<Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalAddCompanionVisible} >
        <Button
        block
        style={{ marginTop: 20}}>
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}  >Add Another Companion</Text>
      </Button>
       <View style={{backgroundColor: "white", height: 120}}> 
     
        </View>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <Button
        block
        style={{ marginTop: 0,width: '40%'}}  onPress={this._toggleModalAddCompanion.bind(this)} >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }} >Cancel</Text>
      </Button>
       <Button
        block
        style={{ marginTop: 0,width: '60%',}}   >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }} >Add</Text>
      </Button>
     </View>
    </Modal>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that solved it was passing transparent={true} in the Modal props

Comment: This was already specified in the accepted answer, can you add more details to your answer so it can stand out on its own?