# put element to alert REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native

im using database in my RN app so im selecting datas and datas in my db are with html tags for an example : `<p>Hello world</p>` and thats why im using **react-native-render-html**

my question is that i want to select data to react native alert and i can do it already but how can i put element to alert value?

```
<Button title="Arka Yaprak" onPress={() => Alert.alert(`${this.state.arkayaprak}`)} />
```

it is working but i should render it

```
<Button title="Arka Yaprak" onPress={() => Alert.alert(<HTML html={this.state.gununolayi} />)} />
```

like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put a component into *Alert.alert()*.

*Alert.alert()* takes the following arguments:

```
Alert.alert(title: string, message?: string, buttons?: AlertButton[], options?: AlertOptions)
```

You can clearly see that it accepts only `string` values for `title` and `message`.

HTML component of *react-native-render-html* renders a *View* and not a *string*. Hence, it cannot be used inside *Alert.alert()*.

However, you can use [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal) to achieve something similar to alert.

Comment: thank you , im gonna use this and i have a question about modal : do have to modal cover all screen ? it is sliding from bottom and covering full screen , can i make it just slide forward top and cover screen 75% from bottom

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703648/set-width-and-height-to-react-native-modal). Normally, I use [Overlay](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/overlay.html) provided by React Native Elements. It's easier to style.